# React-Native Android elevation - How can I show a shadow without interfering with the z axis overlapping?

Tags: react-native

I want to use elevation to show a shadow but it interferes with z-axis of some of my absolutely positioned elements. Is there a way i can show a shadow on an element without affecting the z-axis?

Something like:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{position: 'absolute', right: 16, bottom: 16, elevation: 8}}> // this view is placed first
    <Text>Some text</Text>
  </View>

  <View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 10, left: 10, right: 10, 
bottom: 10, backgroundColor: 'green'}}> // this one second

  </View>
</View>
```

So usually the second one placed will appear on top of the first one, but the first one appears on top in this case due to the elevation. How can I have a shadow on the first view without it appearing on top of the second view?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your problematic code snippet?

Comment: just edited it.